# how to install ubuntu manually with creating or modifying partitions

Tags: partitioning

the major problem which i was facing earlier was extra number of partitions of windows OS. due to which while installing ubuntu  an option appears to install ubuntu alongside host OS but the option was modified and displayed as install ubuntu inside windows, but now i have deleted some partitions but the space is still unallocated, will i be able to install ubuntu in that unallocated space ?
[image]

Comment: While Installing Ubuntu select 'Something Else' And select the unallocated space...

Comment: @AshutoshKale what must i do after that

Comment: Select Unallocated partition (pressing on + button)

Comment: @AshutoshKale ok should i then select the option install now ?? or should i make more partitions from that ??

Comment: @AshutoshKale i think you should post an elaborate answer for this

Comment: sorry  i cant answer now !! please visit http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/

Comment: @AshutoshKale no probs, i'veinstalled it now by my own and hurrah i am back on ubuntu

Comment: This link should solve your problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation